# Probability for Tensorflow Binary Image Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to follow the [Image Classification Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#creating_a_new_network_with_dropouts) but unfortunally it doesn't tell you how to use the model after you've created it.

The code I currently use to create the model is:

```py
model = Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE ,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

On my first attempt I hadn't the `activation='sigmoid'` on the last Dense layer, but then the predictions I get from the model are for example `[[332.9539]]` which I don't know how to interpret.

After I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106372) answer I added the Sigmoid activation to receive a value between 0 and 1, but unfortunally when training the model the accuracy is stuck at 0.5 while it worked before.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the sigmoid activation to the last layer, then you need to remove the `from_logits=True` from the loss instance, since your model is no longer producing logits:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```